# Pip install error colorama

Tags: python, installation, pip

Problem: I istalled Anaconda on Windows 7, I'm under a proxy and I set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`.

after

```
pip install any
```

I get:

> File "C:\Users\dpp1058597\Desktop\Anaconda2\lib\
>
> site-packages\pip_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in
>
> write_plain_text self.wrapped.write(text[start:end]) OError: [Errno 0] Error

Comment: how did you install pip?

Comment: yes... I can install .whl, but I get error with pip download...